# How do I select one of the value option example: <OPTION VALUE='27'>Simulation and Skills</OPTION>

Tags: javascript, html

How do I select one of the value option example: Simulation and Skills to automatically be selected. please help...

```
 <select name="cboArea" id="cboArea" multiple="multiple" onclick="selectOrSelect();" onkeydown="selectOrSelect();" onkeyup="selectOrSelect()" onkeypress="selectOrSelect()">
            <!--<OPTION VALUE=''>All</OPTION>-->

                    <OPTION VALUE='1'>1st Floor</OPTION>

                    <OPTION VALUE='2'>CEC Building</OPTION>
     </select>

    </TD>
    <td>All</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="radAllAreas" id="radAllAreas" onclick="selectAllAreas(this.checked);"/>
```

Comment: where is your js code..

Comment: Check how select works https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: If you're asking for a default value, just add the attribute `selected` to ONE of your `<option>` tags (also as a style tip, it's [recommended by W3 to use lowercase element names](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp) for one simple reason: it looks cleaner)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if it is default value you want to show:

```
 <OPTION VALUE='1' selected>1st Floor</OPTION>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `jQuery`:

```
$("select#cboArea").val("2");
```

Or

```
$("select#cboArea option[value='2']").prop("selected", true);
```

If you want to use `jQuery`, add one of above lines instead of comments in below code:

```
 $(function(){
       //put your jQuery code here.
  });
```

`Pure js`:

```
document.querySelector("select#cboArea").value="2";
```

If you want to use `vanilla js`, add above line at the end of your document (inside of a `script` tag).

Or in `html`:

```
  <option value='2' selected>CEC Building</option>
```